# Finding an element difference between two lists efficiently

Tags: python, list

Given the list `a` and `b`, where `a` has one extra element compared to `b`, I'm trying to locate that extra element that exclusively exists in `a` in an efficient way. While this could be easily done using `set(a) ^ set(b)`, the problem is that `a` and `b` could contain multiple elements with a same name that should be treated independently.

For example:

```
a = ['Orange', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Tomato', 'Orange', 'Watermelon']
b = ['Watermelon', 'Orange', 'Tomato', 'Orange', 'Apple']
```

The result should return the extra `'Orange'` that is in list `a`. My code is:

```
def ListDiff(a, b):
    for element in a:
        if element in b:
            b.remove(element)
        else:
            solution = element
    return solution
```

But obviously using the `remove()` can never be the most efficient and optimized way, especially if `a` and `b` are large. Is there an efficient way to locate the extra element?

Comment: Why remove to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in `O(n log(n))` time using a sort. After sorting, you can do a linear traversal to find the first difference. Duplicate elements complicate binary search, which would otherwise be possible.

```
def ldiff(a, b):
    a.sort()
    b.sort()
    for i, j in zip(a, b):
        if i != j:
            break
    else:
        i, j = a[-1], b[-1]
    return i if len(a) > len(b) else j
```

If you object to the in-place modification preformed by the `sort` method, use the `sorted` function instead.